# Creating very similar types in Julia

Tags: julia

Say I have two types that are both subtypes of an abstract type

```
abstract A

type B <: A
x
y
z
end 

type C <: A
x
y
z
w
end
```

is there any way of creating `C` without having to basically copy/paste `B` and add the extra parameters? The main issue is that `B` and `C` are really close and I would prefer as little code duplication as possible. I know the manual says that concrete types can't subtype each other:

> One particularly distinctive feature of Julia’s type system is that concrete types may not subtype each other: all concrete types are final and may only have abstract types as their supertypes.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can do it with Macros. 
Datastructures.jl goes all out on this technique https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl/blob/master/src/default_dict.jl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In these cases I usually prefer to *compose* my types.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
abstract A

type B <: A
    x
    y
    z
end 

type C <: A
    b::B
    w
end
```

Notice how `C` is still a subtype of `A`, but contains an instance of `B` as a field.

### Update

It is true that you can no longer access `c.x`, but rather you have to do `c.b.x`. There is a simple way around this.

Suppose you have a function

```
function my_func(a::A)
    # do something with a.x, a.y, a.z
end
```

If `my_func` is supposed to work with any subtype of `A`, it can only access fields that are common across all subtypes of `A`. In this case that is `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Knowing that, I would also define a specialized version of that method to dispatch on instances of `C` as follows:

```
my_func(c::C) = my_func(c.b)
```

This is a bit more verbose, but you can easily wrap all these functions in a metaprogramming for loop that uses `@eval` and generate them all at once. See [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/metaprogramming/#code-generation) for more info

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you can't do `C.x` or `C.y`, right? You have to do `C.b.x` so functions can't operate on `B` and `C` identically.

Comment: Yes, that's true. See the update to my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I would do

```
type XYZ
    x
    y
    z
end

type B <: A
    xyz::XYZ
end 

type C <: A
    xyz::XYZ
    w
end
```

Of course, for performance reason I normally use `immutable` as well as annotate as much types as possible.

Comment: This does seem cleaner - the question I have, is there any extra overhead (currently) to accessing x from an instance of type B than with Spencer's method? (I've seen some comments about issues with overhead of types with a single element, so I'm not sure)

Comment: There definitely is because `type` is mutable. The pointer must be stored. The compiler may be able to remove the store in very specific cases, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Have you tried checking the output of `@code_llvm` and `@code_native` for this kind of question?

Answer (score 2):

I do that with macros (as mentioned in the comments above). The subtypes remain separated, which is often more natural than sub-subtyping:

```
abstract A
macro A_fields()
        quote
                a1
                a2
        end
end

type B <: A
        @A_fields
        b1
end

type C <: A
        @A_fields
        c1
end
```

The major drawback is that when you cange `A_fields()`, you have to manually change all constructors for the subtypes of `A`.